# How to update mysql database from android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am using php with httpost to get data from an external mysql database. But i dont know how to update the mysql database from android. How would i do this.( I have a large string array which i want to enter into a relational datbase where id= ' unique  id' and indexes other table which must be created dynamically when the user installs the application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using JSON, here's a great tutorial for you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php